# Left column starts after right column

Tags: beamer

I wanted a frame with an example composed by a description and an image but the result is not what I want and I don't know where the problem is...

```
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\frametitle{Classical Definition}
\begin{example}
    \begin{columns}[t]
        \begin{column}{5cm}
            Description
        \end{column}

        \begin{column}{5cm}
            \includegraphics[width=4cm]{fig/nrpexample.png}
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{example}
\end{frame}
```

[image: not wanted space marked with red arrow]

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3):

Change `t` by `T`

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\frametitle{Classical Definition}
\begin{example}
    \begin{columns}[T]
        \begin{column}{5cm}
            Description
        \end{column}

        \begin{column}{5cm}
            \includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image}
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{example}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to have this:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\PassOptionsToPackage{demo}{graphicx}
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
    \frametitle{Classical Definition}
    \begin{example}
        \begin{columns}
            \begin{column}[T]{5cm}
                Description
            \end{column}%       
            \begin{column}[T]{5cm}
                \includegraphics[width=4cm]{fig/nrpexample.png}
            \end{column}
        \end{columns}
    \end{example}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It works, even if I had to add a vertical space at the beginning of each column.
I don't understand why my code is does not work as well

Comment: "`T` is similar to the `t` option, but `T` aligns the tops of the first lines while `t` aligns the so-called baselines of the first lines. If strange things seem to happen in conjunction with the `t` option (for example if a graphic suddenly “drops down” with the `t` option instead of “going up,”), try using this option instead." (from the manual)

Comment: Ok, thanks for the information. I have chosen to use the `T` option but applied to the `columns` environnement, without the use of `\PassOptionsToPackage` command

Comment: @Vavou Yes, that is the same in this case. The `\PassOption.....` is just added in order to make your code compilable. As I do not have `fig/nrpexample.png`, I could not compile your code. You should always try to make the MWE as simple as possible.